# Central extension of the Heisenberg Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to compute $H^2(\frak h_3, \mathbb R)$ where $\frak h_3$ is the Heisenberg algebra and $\mathbb R$ is a trivial $\frak h_3$-module. From my attempt the cohomology seems to be two dimensional, however I haven't been able to find any example for computations of this kind online and I'm a bit unsure if I did this right.

Here's my attempt. (I'm going to write $\frak h_3$ as $\frak g$ to avoid too many subscripts)

Let $x, y, z$ be the generators of $\frak g$ satisfying $[y, z] = x$ and all other brackets zero. If $\omega \in C^2(\frak g, \mathbb R) = {\rm Alt}(\frak g^2, \mathbb R)$ then the differential
$$d\omega(x, y, z) = -\omega([x, y], z) + \omega([x, z], y) - \omega([y, z], x) = -\omega(x, x) = 0$$
so all $2$-cochains are $2$-cocycles, $Z^2({\frak g}, \mathbb R) = C^2(\frak g, \mathbb R)$.

Now we want to compute the differential $d\alpha(u, v) = -\alpha([u, v])$ for any $1$-cochain $\alpha$.
We can use the dual basis $x^*, y^*, z^*$ for $C^1(\frak g, \mathbb R) = \frak g^*$ and the basis $x^*\wedge y^*, x^* \wedge z^*, y^*\wedge z^*$ for $Z^2(\frak g, \mathbb R)$. Since $[-, -] : \frak g\wedge\frak g \to \frak g$ sends $y\wedge z$ to $x$ and all the other basis elements to zero we have $dx^* = -y^*\wedge z^*$ and $dy^* = dz^* = 0$, thus the image of $d$ is a one dimensional subspace of $Z^2$ resulting in $\dim H^2 = \dim Z^2 - \dim B^2 = 2$.

Is this the right way to proceed? Is there some relevant literature I could read for this kind of explicit computations?

Comment: See also Example $1.3.18$ [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_17_lie_coho_course.pdf) (in German), how to compute the cohomology $H^2(L,\Bbb R)$ for nilpotent Lie algebras $L$ explicitly.